# Confusing Input From Joystick Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, joystick

I am working on a Unity3D project that uses an XBox-360 Controller as the input. I am using the Unity input Manager to select the inputs. All of the Inputs are set up the exact same. However, the right joystick keeps acting like it is being pushed in one direction or another, while the left joystick works as it should.

Here is the setup

Gravity:      3

Dead:         0.001

Sensitivity:  3

Snap:         False

Type:         Joystick Axis

---

The Joystick that works is using the **4th Axis** The Joysticks that don't work use the **X and Y Axes**

Comment: That seems like a really low deadband value... Have you tried raising it? How about using a different controller? The purpose of the deadband is to prevent drift if a joystick is slightly off-center while at rest, which is what seems to be the case.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja That should really be an answer. solved my problem thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same with my controller, especially in games like Dolphin emulator. I set the deadzone individually per joystick since they seem to be slightly different, though it doesn't go much over 16%.